# $(document).ready calling two times

Tags: jquery, datatable, cross-domain

I have 2 application one is based on struts and other one is spring.

I am calling one url from struts application to spring and getting the response as model(which is a jsp page). and in that model jsp page I have one document.ready function. and for first time loading I am showing showing one datatable. and I have another link above the datatable when I click that link it it is calling ajax function to the spring app and it should open another datatable and will hide the existing datatable. But the document.ready is loading again and so it is showing the previous datatable. But if I click the link second time then it is showing correct datatable.

struts app:

```
    <body>
<div id="divcontent"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {


         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/employee/index.app?id=1234',
         data: "" ,
        success: function(response){
            $('#divcontent').html(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
        console.log(e)
        }
    });


    });
</script>
```

and some part of response code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {alert(211);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache : false
        });
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $('#spinnerBlock').addClass('spinner-block');
            $('#cndLoadSpinnerModal').show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
            $('#spinnerBlock').removeClass('spinner-block');
            $('#cndLoadSpinnerModal').hide();
        });
        if (isUserRoleAdmin) {
            loadAdminUserTable();
        } else {
            alert(21);
            loadCandidateTable();                   
        }
    });
```

I am thinking since the entire response is coming as html content and loading to struts app from spring app so struts app is not recognizing that document.ready is already loaded or not thats why it is calling again.

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you would use `$(window).on('load', handler);` instead, it should easily fix your issue. That's said, i guess you should maybe rethink your logic and better way should be available regarding your expected behaviour. One other way could be to explecitely avoid reloading specifc script from loaded content

Comment: @Wolff where I need to use $(window).on('load',handler) in the response html or struts app?

Comment: If i understand your issue, you don't want to fire the document ready handler from response if the document is already in ready state. So instead, replace this document ready wrapper with `$(window).on('load', function(){...});` which wouldn't be recalled if window is already loaded (unlinke document pseudo ready event which use a promise internally).

Comment: If I use window load then it is not calling loadCandidateTable() funciton

Comment: But i was guessing it was your expected behaviour... So indeed i completly misunderstood what you are lloking for. Which part of document ready code don't you want to be loaded? In fact, what is exactly your issue? I still don't get it

Comment: This is happening because of different application as the html is coming from spring.war and appending into the application struts.war. I am still clue less how to fix this.

Comment: I fixed this issue. I changed the anchor tag href from href="#" to href="javascript:void(0)" and it worked.